# Getting an uploaded JavaScript file from Gmail draft

Tags: gmail

Starting in February 2017, Gmail blocks JavaScript attachments. My problem is that I have a Gmail draft, created before February, with a JS attachment that I now can't access. Is there something I can do about it?

Here's a screen snapshot of the bottom of my Gmail draft (the attachment is called "working_with_object.js") and underneath it the DOM hierarchy, maybe it would be useful for help:

[image]

Comment: Grasping at straws here, but could you use a third-party client like Thunderbird to get the message?

Comment: @ale, it actually worked. You can post this as an answer

Comment: I can, but I'm shy on details, like is there an actual "drafts" folder created. I'll make it CW; if you could add the extra details that'd be great.

Comment: Not sure what extra details are needed. I guess every Gmail account has a "drafts" folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message and its attachment still exists, I'd expect a third-party email client (such as [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/)) should be able to download the message, and Google won't be involved in trying to protect you from a possibly malicious attachment.

It makes sense to me that Google prevents access to JavaScript files. Gmail itself is a *lot* of JavaScript, and it would be pretty easy to really mess up your mailbox by tricking you into running a malicious file. Of course, I'd think they could make an exception to a file that you've uploaded and attached to a draft message.